# Slow Mysql Query / In Clause

Tags: mysql, zip

I have a database with ~100,000 entries - right now my query looks like this:

> SELECT id,zipcode,price FROM listings WHERE zipcode IN (96815 , 96815,
>   96835, 96828, 96830, 96826, 96836, 96844, 96816, 96847, 96814, 96822,
>   96823, 96843, 96805, 96806, 96810, 96848, 96808, 96809, 96842, 96839,
>   96802, 96812, 96804, 96803, 96840, 96807, 96813, 96841, 96801, 96850,
>   96811, 96898, 96837, 96827, 96824, 96846, 96821, 96817, 96859, 96838,
>   96819, 96820, 96858, 96849, 96825, 96795, 96863, 96818, 96853, 96861,
>   96734, 96744, 96701, 96860, 96709, 96782, 96706, 96797, 96862, 96789,
>   96707, 96730, 96854, 96759, 96786, 96857, 96717, 96792, 96762, 96712,
>   96791, 96731) AND (price BETWEEN 1000 AND 1200) ORDER BY id

This query worked fine when I had only 50,000 entries, but its getting really slow when I extend the radius of the zip codes (which results in even more zip codes in the in clause).

> id    int(8)  AUTO_INCREMENT                           price  mediumint(7)
>   zipcode   mediumint(5)

All three fields are indexed. Does anyone have an idea how i could optimize it? Thanks guys

Comment: I am pretty sure that if you have that many zip codes in an IN clause even if the field is indexed it will run slow. I am not sure how to fix this though besides limiting the number of zips.

Comment: I can see duplicated values in the list of zip code. Make sure you only give distinct values and increments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ZIP codes are generally geographically distributed -- you might be able to speed things up by simplifying the ZIP code clause to something like:

```
zipcode BETWEEN 96700 AND 96898
```

This may end up inadvertently including some zip codes that you didn't want, but it may end up being more efficient to filter them out later.

Comment: Sounds plausible - seems it helps a bit

Answer (score 0):

There is a big difference between each field being indexed and fields being indexed correctly.
As far as I can see you only need one index to make your query run faster

Try create an index with the following columns (zipcode, price)

Comment: The problem is that I have other queries as well (so I need the index for the other two columns). The main concern is the zip query.

Comment: That's fine if the indexes are used by other queries, but what I meant was that, just because you have an index on a column, it does not mean that your query can use it. Create the index with both columns in it and let me know if it helps.